# Symfony completely ignores all the changes I make to code

Tags: php, model-view-controller, wamp, symfony

I tried to click `ctrl + r` and `ctrl + f5`, and also cleared the cache and launched the application on other browsers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZLT.png)

Anything I do at `app/recources/views/default/index.html.twag` is completely ignored, I even tried deleting the whole content of this file, and then restarted pc and it still appears as default view. Any changes made to the controller are also ignored. It finally starts to notice me when I completely delete `index.html.twag` file. When I return it back (completely empty by the way), it shows me its default view AGAIN!!! Please any ideas?

Comment: You're probably editing the wrong file. Maybe there is more than one installation or source file location?

Comment: There is one symfony file installed at wamp64/www folder, and there only one project.

Comment: Can you go to `C:\wamp64\www\wtf\app_dev.php` then click on the debug bar bottom of the page. Then click 'Configuration' on the left menu (last item), and look if there is any cache activated (OPcache, APC, etc)

Comment: It is actualy kinda mind blown, because there is only one symfony project, and i sure I am editing exactly this project. But if i make changes to view index (for example delete content). How is it even possible to show me some content even after restarding pc and deleting browser cashe.

Comment: $kernel->loadClassCache(); this is the only line that contains word Cache at my web/app_dev folder.

Comment: $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

Comment: found these three line at wtf/web/app.php;  //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel); was commented by default, not sure what it does, maybe it is the problem?

Comment: Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Comment: Preciel thanks for your answer, not quet sure what you asked me to do, but thats my code at the place you mentioned.

Comment: Added additional page to views, and tried to visit it (added function to control to create route to that view) and it said 404 not found. I think it ignors completely whole code, unless I delete something. Maybe it's nothing to do with cache maybe it is something else?

Answer (score 3):

So eventually the problem was with the cache. All I had to do was to run a command at my console: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`(this will clear production level cache)
Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html

Comment: It's very important to clearly describe what you have done when trying to fix the issue. In the original post you say you've tried clearing the cache and launching it in other browsers. Since clearing the cache is such a normal operation when developing with Symfony it's very easy to mistake the browser cache clear with the symfony cache clear

Comment: I am new to Symfony and fresh to web development, sorry for this missunderstanding. In the future I will try to be more clear, thanks fo comment, have a great day and Happy New Year!

Comment: Just wanted to mention it, have fun working with Symfony. You're surely not the first one who has struggled with caching :) Happy new year!

Comment: The fact that you had to use env=prod strongly implies you are working in production mode and not development mode.  In most cases you do not have to fool with the cache in development mode.  Are you getting the debug toolbar?  If not then you are working in production mode using app.php instead of app_dev.php.

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to your Twig files or your controllers, you should always clear the cache using:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

for your production environment.

The DEV environment is done automatically, but sometimes you still need to clear it with:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

To access the DEV environment, just append `app_dev.php` to your route URL. For example:  http://localhost/wtf/app_dev.php

If you open that file under the web folder, you'll see you can also add in the IP addresses of remote hosts that you want to allow access.

Hope that helps you.